# Reading distinct local secondary index keys of a DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

Assume I have `staff` table with primary key composing of `organization_id` as *partition key* and `staff_id` as *sort key*. On the other hand I have `department` local secondary index with `department_id` as *sort key*.

```
{
  ...
  KeySchema: [
    { AttributeName: "organization_id", KeyType: "HASH"},
    { AttributeName: "staff_id", KeyType: "RANGE" }
  ],
  LocalSecondaryIndexes: [
    {
        IndexName: "department",
        KeySchema: [
            { AttributeName: "organization_id", KeyType: "HASH"},
            { AttributeName: "department_id", KeyType: "RANGE" }
        ],
        Projection: {
            ProjectionType: "KEYS_ONLY"
        }
    }
  ],
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    { AttributeName: "organization_id", AttributeType: "S" },
    { AttributeName: "staff_id", AttributeType: "S" },
    { AttributeName: "department_id", AttributeType: "S" }
  ]
  ...
}
```

As one may easily figure out, there are many items with different `staff_id` sharing same `department` index key. I need to query list of departments of an organization with given `organization_id`. Is there a way to retrieve this list from `staff` table? I do not prefer to maintain another `departments` table. I am new to DynamoDB, so if you have any comments/advices on overall table design, all is very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there is no direct feature of distinct in DynamoDB, but you can achieve this by following ways.

1. Query you LSI and get all records for organizationId and then at application level you find out distinct values.(This is very common practice in NoSql DB's)
2. As you have mention create another table, now I would recommend that you create another table that way you can directly retrieve only selected values
3. [CloudSearch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-dynamodb-data.html): Can be integrated into DynamoDB tables then you can directly search in Cloudsearch instead of a table, but this is useful when you have multiple search queries and millions of records.

Thanks

Comment: I ended up maintaining `departments` table.